# How to fix "ERROR: Unable to find method 'proguard.KeepClassSpecification."

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am trying to integrate proguard in my android project.

```
    debug {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        useProguard true
    //shrinkResources true
       minifyEnabled true
    }
```

After adding this bloc of code, i keep getting this error when i try to synchronise my gradle

```
ERROR: Unable to find method 'proguard.KeepClassSpecification.<init>(ZZZZZZZLproguard/ClassSpecification;Lproguard/ClassSpecification;)V'.
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi! did you solve this issue? I tried to solve it by updating com.android.tools.build:gradle to 4.0.1 but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to 4.0.1.